Switch mount's backing device
I'm looking into removing lvm from a root filesystem without reboot or umount.
I was planning on mimicking the lvm device with dmsetup, changing the mount to the new device, then removing lvm. However, I've failed to find a way to change the mount to a new device without unmounting first. I know that this would be crazy to do in many scenarios, but in this one, it is the same filesystem.
I've looked through mount and vfs source code but have failed to find a way. I've also tried tricking lvremove by changing its dmsetup device table to one that goes through a series of other dmsetup devices and loop devices.
It goes against what I want, but I might just end up setting up a parent dmsetup device and rebooting with it mounted instead of the lvm device. Then, hopefully, I can change the parent table to whatever I want and remove lvm.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with dmsetup; what is the new backing device? What's the point of creating the same dmsetup device already created by LVM? If your LVM is not spanning multiple devices and not fragmented (each LV is a single segment), you can map it to regular partitions. That way LVM is removed… effective next reboot.

Same backing device. The point is to migrate off lvm without reboot or umount. I am aware I can map it to a regular partition and reboot. Users and I don't want a reboot. I figured it would be trivial with all that Linux can do.

Most filesystems can't jump ship. So you're stuck with whatever device you mounted, until you umount or remount it. In large part that is what makes Device Mapper / LVM so useful... it can resize and move things around, where filesystems do not support such shenanigans. With regular partitions, you're stuck and most changes will require reboots.

Perhaps. I'm going to look into using a module to change s_bdev in the kernel super_block structure. Will post the results.
